# Angular 2 doesnt update view after changed value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

Given following Angular 2 code finding current position and converting to human-readable string -> binding to input element:

html tempalte:

```
<input name="myAddr" [(ngModel)]="form.address" type="text">
<button (click)="findMyLocation()" class="ui location right blue icon button">
  <i class="marker icon"></i>
</button>
```

Angular 2 code:

```
form: {
    volume: number,
    thickness: number,
    density: number,
    address: string
  } = { address: '', volume: 0, thickness: 100, density: 300 };

findMyLocation(){
    $('.location').addClass('loading');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.geocoder.geocode({location: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude }}, (results, status)=>{
        if(status == 'OK')
          if(results[0]){
            $('.location').removeClass('loading');
            console.log('Addr: ' + results[0].formatted_address);
            this.form.address = results[0].formatted_address;
          }
      })
    }, fail => {
      console.log(fail);
    });
  }
```

However when I click button, location(lat, lng) are converted to humar readable adress, and I can see output to console. But input element doesnt change. If I click again on button, element gets update as it should be. 
Whats going on guys?
[image: Screen-1, Clciked][image: Screen-2, clicked twice]

Comment: As far as I know Angular does not watch the changes in the object properties, but only the object itself (its reference). If you replace the `form` with new object then you'll see the changes in your view.

Comment: Just tested, declaring other single string variable doenst work aswell :( It worked if I click twice on button but this is unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bacause navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is asynchromous function, you have to use ngZone.run to let angular rerender the models.

```
this.ngZone.run(function() {
  this.form.address = results[0].formatted_address;
};)
```

Note: you have to import `NgZone` and `inject` it at your constructor.

UPD: there are two ways as i know:

- ngZone.run()
- ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Comment: thanks! worked like charm. So, every third-party library's asyc function should run inside ngZone?

Comment: @EvghenyKalkutin I have update the answer for your comment. since for me, i  always use the first one which is equivalent to  $scope.$apply() often used in angular1.x